# Symfony2 rest and oauth, can't persist session

Tags: session, symfony

I'm using FosRestBundle and FosOauthServerBundle for an api with Symfony.

I have a route `/login/username/password`, in this action i loggin the user manually :

```
            $encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
            $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());

            if ($user->getPassword() == $encoded_pass) {
                $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $password, "api", $user->getRoles());
                $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

                $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->get("request"), $token);
                $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
            }
```

If i check in my database after that (i save session in my database) i have a new line, and at the end of my action, if i check `$this->getUser()` i have the good one.

But after that, in another action, if i check $this->getUser() i have noting... I can't retrieve a user session from an action to another.

Do you have any ideas ?

Ediy: If i check `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()`i have :

```
{"roles":[{"role":"ROLE_USER"}],"authenticated":true,"attributes":[],"token":"MYTOKEN"}
```

But i haven't my user..

Comment: What if you try to retrieve user via security context / token ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fetch your user from security context. I usually define this as a separate function in the controllers where i need it :

```
public function getConnectedUser()
{
    $user = null;

    if ($this->get('session')->has('_security_member') && !is_null($this->get('security.context')->getToken())) {
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    return $user;
}
```

You can then access it from every action of your controller.

```
$user = $this->getConnectedUser();
```

Comment: It's the same with this function, i have nothing, no error, my route just do nothing..

Comment: If i return "string" i can see my return value, but ifi return$user, i can't see anything, nothing happend. I can't check a var_dump()... Weird

Comment: What if you try to access a property of your $user ? Error could be helpful : `var_dump($user->getUsername());`

Comment: The condition is not true, i can't get $user. All returns after the condition aren't executed

Comment: What if you remove the first condition `$this->get('session')->has('_security_member')` ?